# Conditionally rendered fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience, case, dynamic-visualforce

looking for general ideas on how to approach the requirements below:

---

"Create a Case" button/action on Account’s Lightning record page:

1. Ability to choose from different record types and corresponding Case_Category_c custom field
2. AccountId is passed from Account record into new Case
3. Depending on the record type and Case Category, dynamically render the necessary fields and further allow continuous re-rendering depending on values in those fields, e.g. Select a new value in a picklist, form re-renders and fields appear/hide as needed
4. Upon save, user is redirected to new Case
5. When viewing or editing a Case, the fields on the page layout are dynamically rendered per logic defined in original case creation
6. Must work in standard app or console app

---

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

- Tried overriding Case new button with Visualforce page and custom controller that redirected to another Visualforce page, however,

  1. it doesn’t work in a console app, and
  2. our users won’t likely create Cases outside of launching from Account page
- A screen flow. It got very complex, there are 100+ case categories, and I think will be a pain to manage in the long run. Also doesn’t account for viewing/editing the page, just creation.
- LWC that opened a new console tab with the VF page from a button click. My favorite solution so far, but I cannot figure out how to pass the `AccountId` from the LWC into the Visualforce page. I am very new to LWC and need to dive deeper.

What am I missing? Any advice on how to approach the design would be greatly appreciated.

(I know dynamic forms are potentially around the corner for Cases, which could ease some of this, but we need a solution now.)

Comment: The obvious solution to this is dynamic forms. Unfortunately Case support is planned for summer '23 so you probably can't wait for that.

Comment: Is having a child custom object "Case Details" a crazy idea? That way we can use Dynamic forms and then in the future, migrate those to the actual Case Object

Comment: It doesn't have to be a child, but instead a placeholder; you create a "Case Details" object and on insert you create a Case from it (then throw away the Case Details perhaps). It's certainly doable if you don't need anything that cannot be achieved in a custom object, at least for the case creation... (It's not so crazy as a short term solution IMHO, just so long as you have a plan for getting rid of it once Case is supported for Dynamic Forms).